Azure Static Web App deployment fails when using licensed npm package in GitHub Actions
I am trying to deploy a Static Web App from GitHub to Azure using the Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1 action. However, the deployment fails when I attempt to use a licensed npm package. The action does not seem to accept the license credentials for the private npm registry.
How can I properly configure the GitHub Actions workflow to use the licensed npm package and successfully deploy the Static Web App to Azure?
Below is the yaml file
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - dev

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          submodules: true

      - name: Configure npm registry
        run: echo "@infragistics:registry=https://packages.infragistics.com/npm/js-licensed/" >> ~/.npmrc

      - name: Configure npm authentication token
        run: echo "//packages.infragistics.com/npm/js-licensed/:_auth=${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}" >> ~/.npmrc

      - name: Verify npm configuration
        run: npm config list

      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          action: "upload"
          app_location: "./Frontend" # Adjust this path if necessary
          output_location: "./build" # Adjust this path if necessary

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN }}
          action: "close"

When I run the workflow, I encounter the following error:
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@infragistics%2figniteui-react - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@infragistics/igniteui-react@^18.6.0' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /github/home/.npm/_logs/2024-06-10T09_31_49_347Z-debug-0.log


---End of Oryx build logs---
Oryx has failed to build the solution.


If possible , can you share your github repo?

Sorry it is private repository

Well I think it's easy to guess what happened based on the error - considering the @infragistics/igniteui-react is supposed to be installed from a private registry but the error is 404 from registry.npmjs.org, so the npmrc is not being respected simply put.
The actual Configure npm registry steps look correct

Don't see an explicit install step, so assuming Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1 action handles that? In that case the issue likely lies with how that action performs the config and install

Seems like the (otherwise correct looking) configuration being added to the root .npmrc are not being respected considering the package error is because it can't be found on the default registry.npmjs.org.
A direct npm i/ci command with this config will work (tested the same setup), however since the install is handled by the Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1 action, the configuration should likely work for their specifics.
There's very little described on how that happens in the official docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/build-configuration?tabs=github-actions#build-and-deploy but from what I can gather there's a custom build tool involved (https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx) and that build in a container - as in it moves the source where the root ~/.npmrc no longer exists.
Looking at https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/44#issuecomment-1597629465 seems like the suggested usage is to apply any config in a local to the project .npmrc instead. So, unless there's already one in your project root, you should be able to just change the commands to write to a local file intead:
run: echo "..." >> .npmrc

Note: Not entirely certain which part of the project is being copied, so it might be needed to match the app_location and write to ./Frontend/.npmrc instead, so you might need to try that too - let me know if so and I'll edit the final answer.
This way the file will be at project root and should get copied to the build container and thus be respected for the install.
